# What are "Relocated Items" folder in macOS Catalina 10.15.4?

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

10.15.4 Catalina update has left me with a new folder called "Relocated Items". Inside was a folder within a folder called "etc" which contains the following "master.passwd.system_default". I am having difficulty opening this file in text editor (seemed like the logical choice). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This support article from Apple should help with your query:

- [If you see a Relocated Items folder after upgrading macOS on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchl8ae423a3/mac)

> When you upgrade your Mac to macOS Catalina, all your files and data are carefully reviewed to ensure they’re valid and authorised, undamaged, and in the correct locations. Some of your files couldn’t be moved to their new locations and were placed in a Relocated Items folder. You can find the Relocated Items folder in the Shared folder within the User folder. The PDF document in the Relocated Items folder explains what to do with files placed in this folder.

Comment: Thanks for the reference and your courtesy.

Comment: This is a helpful answer, but why is it so common that "master.passwd.system_default" is constantly being relocated with every OS update?